# Changing file extention

Tags: rename

In a folder I have a .run file and am trying to change the extension to .clu. The problem is that I have tried

```
rename 's/.run$/.clu/' *.run
```

But this does absolutely nothing to the file.

Note: I'm not trying to convert the file, just to rename the extension.

Comment: Do you have write permission on the file?

Comment: I do have write permission.

Comment: Please, show the name of the files you are trying to rename. `ls` or whatever is useful.

Comment: `for file in *.run ; do mv -f $file \`echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)run/\1clu/'\` ; done` this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what your problem is. What you've posted works:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/test{01..10}.run
$ rename 's/\.run$/.clu/' test/*.run -vn
test/test01.run renamed as test/test01.clu
test/test02.run renamed as test/test02.clu
test/test03.run renamed as test/test03.clu
test/test04.run renamed as test/test04.clu
test/test05.run renamed as test/test05.clu
test/test06.run renamed as test/test06.clu
test/test07.run renamed as test/test07.clu
test/test08.run renamed as test/test08.clu
test/test09.run renamed as test/test09.clu
test/test10.run renamed as test/test10.clu
```

The `-vn` is just telling us what it would do if run without it.

I'm escaping the dot (otherwise it's a REGEX "anything") but it really makes no difference here. It works as well without it.

---

Is it possible that you're actually running `rename.ul`? Check to make sure you're using the Perl rename (which takes the syntax we're using) with `dpkg -S $(readlink -f $(which rename))`

- `perl: /usr/bin/prename` is good.
- `util-linux: /usr/bin/rename.ul` is bad. For some reason you're using a very limited version of rename. Something very squiffy has happened.

For the moment, see if `prename` exists (you could just use that for now) and if not, start asking why Perl isn't installed properly. It would suggest you don't have Ubuntu installed.

Or if you're happy using `rename.ul`, the following should work:

```
rename.ul .run .clu *.run
```

But that might munch a file like `test.run.hooray.run` into `test.clu.hooray.clu` which obviously isn't great.

Comment: looking at your code, it could be the fact that after the 's' you have '/\' while I only have '/', this may be my problem. I'll try it out.

Comment: @RussellHickey As I commented on another, now deleted answer, it makes absolutely no difference here. As you had it, `.` means "any character", while `\.` means `.` - they both work here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to use `rename` for this. You can do it using `basename`:

```
for f in *run; do mv "$f" "$(basename "$f" .run)".clu; done
```

`basename` will print a file's name (no path) and also removes an optional suffix. Therefore, `"$(basename "$f" .run)".clu` is the name of the file `$f` with the `.run` extension replaces with `clu`.

You can also just use bash's own [string manipulation features](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
for f in *run; do echo mv "$f" "${f%%.run}".clu; done
```

The construct `${var%%string}` removes the string `string` from the end of the variable `$var`.

Answer (score 2):

My prefered in cases like this is `mmv` (it is not installed by default in Ubuntu, but you can install it using `sudo apt-get install mmv` command):

```
mmv -n '*.run' '#1.clu'
```

The `-n` means that it's a test run and will not actually change any files. It will show you a list of files that would be renamed if you removed the `-n`. In the case above, it will convert all files in the current directory from a file extension of `.run` to `.clu`.

```
mmv -v '*.run' '#1.clu'
```

The `-v` is optional, but it's a good idea to include it because it is the only record you will have of changes that were made by the rename command.

See [`man mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mmv.1.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You just use `mv`:

```
mv oldname newname
```

`mv` is used to move/ rename files. Refer to the man page of mv for more.

Comment: This will be used in a build file so the names will not be known.

Comment: You could do `mv *.run *.clu` if you are sure that you want to rename all `*.run` files to `*.clu` in the directory you are executing this command.

Comment: this will give the output name as '*.clu' I was trying to just change extention.

Comment: `for file in *.run ; do mv $file echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)run/\1clu/' ; done` this has seemed to worked

Comment: @Jobin `mv *.run *.clu` will either fail or move all `*run` files and all but one `*clu` file into a directory ending with `clu` if one happens to exist and in the right alphabetical order. In any case, it will most certainly will not simply change the extensions.